# How to fix BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain code 3 Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I try to run WorkManager in flutter, create callback, initialize workmanager, but not working... I try to open in real device but unsuccessful... The exception I receive is that:

```
See the error for details: Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"., null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Workmanager.registerOneOffTask (package:workmanager/src/workmanager.dart:192:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _FeedPage.carregarInfo (package:findufront/page/FeedPage.dart:90:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Main.dart:

```
//IMPORTS...



void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    print("Native called background task: $task"); //simpleTask will be emitted here.
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}


void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  await _configureAmplify();
  runApp( MainApp());
}
...
```

Call the workManager:

```
await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
        "taskOne", "backup",
        initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10)
        );
```

Comment: Are you running in Android/iOS?